# Displaying HTML Sections Sequentially with CSS Only

Tags: html, css, css-transitions

See the HTML code below. What CSS code will accomplish the following:

On load, section one displays for a specified period of time and disappears. Then section two displays for a specified period of time and disappears; then section three followed by section four  in the same manner as the previous sections. The entire thing repeats.

```css
section {margin: 50px 40%;}
```

```html
<section id="one">
  <div class="content">Some stuff</div>
</section>
<section id="two">
  <div class="content">Some other stuff</div>
</section>
<section id="three">
  <div class="content">More of the same</div>
</section>
<section id="four">
  <div class="content">Ditto</div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at [CSS animations](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_animations.asp). You can use keyframes to hide and show your sections with something like this:

```css
@keyframes show{
  0% {opacity: 0}
  10% {opacity: 1}
  25% {opacity: 0}
}
```

Then, you can use `animation-delay` to delay the start of each section:

```
#one{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 40s infinite;
}
#two{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 40s infinite;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}
#three{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 40s infinite;
  animation-delay: 20s;
}
#four{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 40s infinite;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
```

With a little bit of tweaking and math, you can get your desired result!

A snippet of my code:

```css
@keyframes show{
  0% {opacity: 0}
  10% {opacity: 1}
  25% {opacity: 0}
}

#one{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 40s infinite;
}
#two{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 40s infinite;
  animation-delay: 10s;
}
#three{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 40s infinite;
  animation-delay: 20s;
}
#four{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: show 40s infinite;
  animation-delay: 30s;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <style>
    section {
      margin: 50px 40%;
    }
  </style>
  <section id="one">
    <div class="content">Some stuff</div>
  </section>
  <section id="two">
    <div class="content">Some other stuff</div>
  </section>
  <section id="three">
    <div class="content">More of the same</div>
  </section>
  <section id="four">
    <div class="content">Ditto</div>
  </section>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. I tried using the animations but could not get the timing right.